# Python. тип данных byte хранит символ, как исправить, чтобы он хранил 16-ричный код

Tags: python-3.x

Как сделать чтобы он хранил что-то на подобии этого S=[b'\x02',b'\x0A',b'\x05', b'\x0B',b'\x09',b'\x0E',b'\x08',b'\x0D', b'\x0C',b'\x04',b'\x06',b'\x07',b'\x00',b'\x03',b'\x0F',b'\x01'], а не этого  b')', b'Y', b'I', b'q'?

Comment: хранит то он одно и тоже это проблема показа, видимо,сделано для читаемости. а зачем вам оно? если захотите получить такое представление, можно `bytes('q', encoding = 'utf-8')   => 
b'q'
>>> hex(ord(bytes('q', encoding = 'utf-8'))) =>
'0x71' Но это будет уже str

Comment: Спасибо, как раз нужно для вывода